# WordPress insert readmore link to the blog page after certain length of content

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am just newbie to the WordPress. In my blog page I want after certain length of characters there will be read more link and if some one clicks on the read more link then he will be able to read that certain content in full. Now I can insert readmore hyperlink in the post page manually but I don't want it manually. So can someone kindly help me out here? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Check [the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) function in documentation just update your template's `index.php`  or the file (could be a template part) in which the main loop is available for your home page, where you have

```
the_content()
```

replace it with

```
the_excerpt();
```